# Google Apps Script: copy ranges to new range use connect formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to connect ranges sheetA to SheetB.

```
sheet A ==================================
         A      B      C      D      E      F    
1                             x      x      x
2

sheet B ==================================
         A             B                C 
1  =sheetA!(A1)  =sheetA!(B1)  =sheetA!(C1)
2
```

i already used copyto, only con copy original link.

```
sheetA.getrange(1,3,1,3).copyto(sheetB.getrange(1,1,1,3))
```

Comment: Try `setFormula()`?

Comment: As i know, setFormula() need to 1 by 1, i what  range by range.
have any way can do this?

Comment: i try to use 

sheetB.getrange(1,1,1,3).setFormulas(sheetA.getrange(1,1,1,3))

just copy SheetA origenal Fomular. 

Ans not this: "=sheetA!(A1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set sheetB!A1 to `=sheetA!A1`
- Then, use autofill to fill up rest of the range

#### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("sheetB");
var sourceRange = sheet.getRange("A1");
sourceRange.setValue("=sheetA!A1")
var destination = sheet.getRange("A1:C20");
sourceRange.autoFill(destination, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```